# A temporary table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have SQL that creates a temporary table and uses it later for further SELECT

```
; WITH tblOrder AS
                (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY I.IsHead DESC, I.InsureeID ASC) AS RowNo, I.InsureeID FROM tblInsuree I
                INNER JOIN(SELECT FamilyID FROM tblInsuree WHERE ValidityTo IS NULL AND CHFID = 1111 AND IsHead = 1) H ON H.FamilyID=I.FamilyID
                WHERE I.ValidityTo IS NULL 
                )

                SELECT I.CHFID InsuranceNumber, I.OtherNames, I.LastName, I.DOB BirthDate, I.Gender, F.Poverty PoveryStatus, C.ConfirmationTypeCode ConfirmationType, F.ConfirmationNo ConfirmationNo, F.FamilyAddress PermanentAddress, I.Marital MaritalStatus, I.CardIssued BeneficiaryCard, l.LocationCode CurrentVillageCode, I.CurrentAddress CurrentAddress, P.Profession, I.Education, I.Phone PhoneNumber, I.Email, I.TypeOfId IdentificationType, I.passport IdentificationNumber, HF.HFCode FSPCode  FROM tblInsuree I
                INNER JOIN tblOrder O ON O.InsureeID = I.InsureeID
                INNER JOIN tblFamilies F ON F.FamilyID = I.FamilyID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblLocations L ON L.LocationId = F.LocationId
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblConfirmationTypes C ON C.ConfirmationTypeCode = F.ConfirmationType
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblFamilyTypes G ON G.FamilyTypeCode= F.FamilyType
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblProfessions P ON P.ProfessionId= I.Profession
                LEFT OUTER JOIN tblHF HF ON HF.HfID= I.HFID
                WHERE
                O.RowNo = 1
                AND F.ValidityTo IS NULL
                AND I.ValidityTo IS NULL
                AND L.ValidityTo IS NULL
                AND HF.ValidityTo IS NULL
```

**I want to replace the code with LINQ**

```
; WITH tblOrder AS
                (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY I.IsHead DESC, I.InsureeID ASC) AS RowNo, I.InsureeID FROM tblInsuree I
                INNER JOIN(SELECT FamilyID FROM tblInsuree WHERE ValidityTo IS NULL AND CHFID = 1111 AND IsHead = 1) H ON H.FamilyID=I.FamilyID
                WHERE I.ValidityTo IS NULL 
                )
```

How do you transfer this part of the code to LINQ and later use it with the rest?

Comment: @NetDev, that doesn't make it a temporary table. What you've got there is what's known as a 'common table expression' (or CTE): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this might work:

```
   var tblOrder = (from I in dbContext.tblInsuree
                      join H in dbContext.tblInsuree.Where(a => a.ValidityTo == null && a.CHFID == 1111 && a.IsHead == 1) on I.FamilyID equals H.FamilyID
                  where I.ValidityTo == null
                  orderby I.IsHead descending, I.InsureeID
                  select I.InsureeID)
                      .ToArray()
                      .Select((InsureeID, RowNo) => new {RowNo = RowNo + 1, InsureeID })
                      .ToArray();
```

Edited according to @NetDev 's comment

Comment: With this everything will be ok `.Select((InsureeID, RowNo) => new
                                            {
                                              RowNo = RowNo + 1,
                                              InsureeID
                                          })`